# Signal "counter & stretcher" mismatch count

Tags: vhdl, counter

I have this small mismatch in my code vhdl code. I'm doing a signal stretcher using a clock counter.
Basically i reiceve an external signal as "start" , after i synchronize it with with a 2 ff synchronizer and use this "syncrhro-start" for my fsm. It read the value in a register and let the "gate" open for the numer of count that i set to the reg.  My clock has a period of 25 ns ( 40MHz clock).
So when i set the value "0" on the register, i don't have any signal (as expected). If i set "1" i have a signal of 50 ns instead of 25ns. 
If i set "2" i have a a 75ns signal-out. Conceptually it is working (2, in binary are 01, so it start to count from 0, so 0-1-2 are 3 clock run/75ns).

But i need to have with "1" a 25ns signal, with 2 a 50ns and so on.

Here my code:

```
                 library IEEE;
               use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
               use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity gate is
Port (
    start : in STD_LOGIC := '0'; --segnale di start
    clk : in  STD_LOGIC; --clock di ingresso
    reset  : in  STD_LOGIC; --ff reset
    gate: out STD_LOGIC; --gate in uscita 
    lenght: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)        
);
end gate;

architecture behavioral of gate is
--type state_type is (idle, gate_up, final);
type state_type is (idle, stretching);
signal state : state_type;


begin


process (reset, clk, start)
variable index : integer :=0;
variable gate_v: std_logic;
variable gatelen : integer;

begin
gatelen := to_integer(unsigned(lenght));

if reset = '1' then  
  gate_v := '0';
  index := 0;
else
    if rising_edge(clk) then
    case state is
      when idle =>
        index := 0;
        gate_v :='0';

        if(start = '1') then
          state <= stretching;
        else
          state <= idle;
        end if;

        when stretching =>
        if index = gatelen then
        state <=idle;
       else
        gate_v := '1';
        index := index + 1;
        state <= stretching;
        end if;            

      when others => null;
    end case;

 end if;
  end if;     
   gate <= gate_v;
   end process; 


  end Behavioral;
```

I can partially fix things withi this mod

gatelen := to_integer(unsigned(lenght))-1;

but in this case, if i put "1" on the registry, i will not have any signal, and if i put "2" i have a output signal of 50ns. The 25ns output signal is still missing.

Any help will be greatly appreciate!

Edit:

Thanks for the Reply, as requested, i will also add the code of my test bench.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity gate_tb is
end gate_tb;

architecture behavioral of gate_tb is

signal master_clk : std_logic := '0';
signal global_rst : std_logic := '0';
signal gate_on : std_logic := '0';
signal gate_out : std_logic := '0';
constant clk_period : time := 25 ns; --40ns
signal lenght_tb : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

component gate is 
    port( 
        clk : in std_logic;  
        reset : in std_logic;         
        start : in std_logic;
        gate: out std_logic;
        lenght: in std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0)
    );
  end component gate;


begin
 uut : gate port map (
        clk => master_clk,
        reset => global_rst,
        start => gate_on,
        gate => gate_out,
        lenght => lenght_tb

        );

       gate_process : process
       begin

         master_clk <= '0';
         wait for clk_period/2;  --for 10 ns signal is '0'.
         master_clk <= '1';
         wait for clk_period/2;  --for next 10 ns signal is '1'.


end process;  

--stimulus

  stim : process 
  begin
  lenght_tb <= "00000001";
  wait for 50 ns;
  global_rst <= '1';
wait for 30 ns;
global_rst <= '0';
wait for 50 ns;
gate_on <= '1';
wait for 35 ns;
gate_on <= '0';
wait for 150 ns;
gate_on <= '1';
wait for 35 ns;
gate_on <= '0';
wait for 150 ns;
gate_on <= '1';
wait for 35 ns;
gate_on <= '0';
wait for 150 ns;
gate_on <= '1';
wait for 35 ns;
gate_on <= '0';
wait for 150 ns;





end process;

end behavioral;
```

So if in this TB i set 
lenght_tb <= "00000000";  the out is 0
is i set 
lenght_tb <= "00000001"; the out is a signal of 50 ns and not 25 ns.

Comment: You don't provide a [mcve] allowing the problem to be replicated without writing a testbench. The answer with the correction provided by my comment works, but without a MCVe how can future readers searching for a soluton to their problem benefit from your problem and it's solution neither of which they can interpret or replicate?

Comment: Your testbench doesn't match your problem description. There are no changes to lenght_tb. You could also note the gate_on (start) signal isn't clock synchronized reflecting *...after i synchronize it with with a 2 ff synchronizer and use this "syncrhro-start" for my fsm*. Your testbench only produces a length one gate output.

Comment: i synchronized the real analog signal using a specific block made by 2 flip flot. At this stage where i can define the signal, i don't find this usefull, I change lenght_tb with the values that i need to simulate. So if i need a "final lenght" of the output signal of 75ns or 3 clock cicles, i set lenght_tb <= "00000011", if i need just 25ns or i set lenght_tb <= "00000001" and so on. In the final project i will configure the "lenght" register externaly using ha command pharser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the state **stretching**, look for example for reg=1:

1. Start=1 then go to state stretching
2. In stretching you increment index, so now index=1 and gate=0
3. Next rising edge (1 clock was passed) index= gatelen so go to idle
4. Next rising edge (another clock so 2 clock were passed) gate=0

You have to set gate=0 when you check if index = gatelen:

```
when stretching =>
        if index = gatelen then
            gate_v :=  '0';
        state <=idle;
       else
        gate_v := '1';
        index := index + 1;
        state <= stretching;
        end if;
```

Comment: `gate_v=‘0’;` is not a variable assignment and also contains non ISO8859-1 characters for the character literal `'0'`. The corrected solution works (`gate_v := '0';`) but can't be replicated without a [mcve] reproducing the problem (and the solution).

Comment: Sorry I missed the double dot

Comment: Thanks Andrea, it work. I'm not so skilled in vhdl, and sometime i miss this "small" things.